# lost python syntax highlight in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax

The syntax highlighting has almost been lost in vscode. 
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qqK5.png)

My vscode version is:

```
Version: 1.40.1 (system setup)
Commit: 8795a9889db74563ddd43eb0a897a2384129a619
Date: 2019-11-13T16:49:35.976Z
Electron: 6.1.2
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18362
```

I have installed all the extensions in the Python Extension Pack (1.6.0).

Operating system: Windows 10

What should I do to restore the syntax highlighting?

Thanks

Comment: you meant `Pylinter` ?

Comment: `CTRL + P` then type `>select linter` and then select `pylint`

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check. One, make sure you have a colour theme chosen which highlights what you want highlighted. Two, make sure that your file has a its language mode set to "Python".

Otherwise VS Code provides Python syntax highlighting out of the box without any extensions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have fixed the issue :)