# vscode python extension stops highlighting syntax

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I've encountered this issue after install/remove cycles of vscode python extension. The syntax highlight is gone and replaced by something very basic. With correct settings, if I type print, then I get the help for print(), extensive information. With the wrong settings or whatever I end up with, I get the "ABC print" with no explanation of the print() function. I tried this but that didn't change the outcome:

[lost python syntax highlight in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58905614/lost-python-syntax-highlight-in-vscode)

I suspect it's a settings issue. I'm not experienced with vscode to hunt down what caused it. Any help is appreciated! BTW, the python code I am testing does run so launch.json has the right target.

settings.json

```
{
"debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.enabled": true
```

}

local.settings.json has nothing python-related.

Answer (score 1):

The `syntax highlight` can be influenced by: `Color Theme` and `editor.tokenColorCustomizations`, `editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations` customization in the settings.json file.

But, obviously, you have not modified these to make you lost almost any `syntax highlight`.

Could you follow these steps to have a check on the color customization?

[image]

[image]

When you switch the `Color Theme`, it will have some changes?

Comment: No grammar or semantic tokens available.
Json displays properly with seemingly correct language etc.

Comment: @liudr Does it work if you switch the color theme?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry I didn't get back to this question soon enough. Between posting the question and now I didn't use vscode. Today I started it, and the syntax highlighting is there. Did it auto updated to august 2021 version and fix the setting issue?

Comment: It's complaining about Linter pylint not being installed. I installed it for both my python and venv python. It seems to be a python module. I restarted vscode after the installs. No issues. I am guessing it's fixed by the update. I didn't switch color scheme but it's on a dark mode probably taking the mode from my win 10 dark mode setting. Thanks for helping! I wish I could find out what caused the issue in the first place.